# Laravel queue timeout issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, supervisord

I have a job which takes upto like 6 hours to complete. I am using laravel database driver for queues and following is the worker:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan queue:work --queue=default,high,medium,low,least --daemon --timeout=86400
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=50
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/worker.log
```

**Issue:**

The jobs while executing gets removed from `jobs` table immediately a process starts executing the queue. However, the job is not completed but it still gets removed form `jobs` table. Ideally it shall stay in `jobs` table till the job is not completed.

Comment: `Ideally it shall stay in jobs table till the job is not completed.`  That isn't how the database driver works, why do you care if it stays in the jobs table until it's completed?

Comment: In order to track whether the job is completed or not, this is the reason to take care whether for this.

Comment: That's not going to be something the jobs table is going to provide to you.  Add your own logic within the Job itself to kick off an event when it finishes..

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I checked with Laravel on Github and they say that this is a part of framework only. Please see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26131#issuecomment-430099675

Please suggest if I am committing any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `Horizon`? If so set a timeout in your `config/horizon.php`, like so:

```
'supervisor-1' =['connection' => 'long_running',
                 'queue'      => 'long_running',
                 'balance'    => 'simple',
                 'processes'  => 1,
                 'tries'      => 1,
                 'timeout'    => 21600], // 6h in seconds
```

Also try adjusting the `retry_after` in `config/queue.php`.

Comment: I am not using Horizon, I am using simple Laravel database driver.